# Home page Redirect to Customer Login Page Magento 2

Tags: customer-account, magento2.3.0

i tried every solution like all commands run setup:upgrade di:compile and content-deploy but nothing effect kindly give me solution 
thank u

[image]

Comment: this might be happening for some 3party extension?

Comment: i  check all extension from my end but i am not sure about anything